# Python 3 object construction: which is the most Pythonic / the accepted way?

Tags: python-3.x, python, conventions

Having a background in Java, which is very verbose and strict, I find the ability to mutate Python objects as to give them with fields other than those presented to the constructor really "ugly".

Trying to accustom myself to a Pythonic way of thinking, **I'm wondering how I should allow my objects to be constructed**.

My instinct is to have to *pass the fields at construction time*, such as:

```
def __init__(self, foo, bar, baz=None):
    self.foo = foo
    self.bar = bar
    self.baz = baz
```

But that can become overly verbose and confusing with many fields to pass. To overcome this I assume the best method is to *pass one dictionary to the constructor, from which the fields are extracted*:

```
def __init__(self, field_map):
    self.foo = field_map["foo"]
    self.bar = field_map["bar"]
    self.baz = field_map["baz"] if baz in field_map else None
```

The other mechanism I can think of is to *have the fields added elsewhere*, such as:

```
class Blah(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

...

blah = Blah()
blah.foo = var1
```

But as that feels *way* too loose for me.

(I suppose the issue in my head is how I deal with *interfaces* in Python...)

So, to reiterate the question: How I should construct my objects in Python? Is there an accepted convention?

Comment: Construction time would be when `__new__` is called. By the time `__init__` is called, the instance already exists and it's *initialization time*.

Comment: @kaizer.se Cheers on the terminology.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first you describe is very common. Some use the shorter

```
class Foo:
   def __init__(self, foo, bar):
       self.foo, self.bar = foo, bar
```

Your second approach isn't common, but a similar version is this:

```
class Thing:
   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
       self.something = kwargs['something']
       #..
```

which allows to create objects like

```
t = Thing(something=1)
```

This can be further modified to

```
class Thing:
   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
       self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
```

allowing

```
t = Thing(a=1, b=2, c=3)
print t.a, t.b, t.c # prints 1, 2, 3
```

As Debilski points out in the comments, the last method is a bit unsafe, you can add a list of accepted parameters like this:

```
class Thing:
    keywords = 'foo', 'bar', 'snafu', 'fnord'
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for kw in self.keywords:
            setattr(self, kw, kwargs[kw])
```

There are many variations, there is no common standard that I am aware of.

Comment: Take care: If you blindly update your `self.__dict__` everyone can overwrite all of your instance methods and variables.

Comment: @Debilski: you absolutely have a point, since it is easy to clobber existing attributes by mistake, but I'd like to note as well that in Python anyone could overwrite your methods and variables anyway, if they wanted to.

Comment: @Debilski: If you use private scoping (ex: `self.__name`), then your methods and variables are hidden from outsiders and can't be modified. See docs: http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers and example: http://codepad.org/EPH6UZd0

Answer (score 3):

I’ve not seen many of your `field_map`s in real life. I think that would only make sense if you were to use the `field_map` at some other place in your code as well.

Concerning your third example: Even though you don’t need to assign to them (other than `None`), it is common practice to explicitly declare attributes in the `__init__` method, so you’ll easily see what properties your object has.

So the following is better than simply having an empty `__init__` method (you’ll also get a higher *pylint* score for that):

```
class Blah(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = None
        self.bar = None

blah = Blah()
blah.foo = var1
```

The problem with this approach is, that your object might be in a not well-defined state after initialisation, because you have not yet defined all of your object’s properties. This depends on your object’s logic (logic in code and in meaning) and how your object works. If it is the case however, I’d advise you **not** to do it this way. If your object relies on `foo` and `bar` to be meaningfully defined, you *should* really put them inside of your `__init__` method.

If, however, the properties `foo` and `bar` are not mandatory, you’re free to define them afterwards.

If readability of the argument lists is an issue for you: Use keyword arguments.