# access to a derived class's parameters

Tags: python

This is a follow-on to a question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11547818/access-to-init-arguments) but I didn't really know enough at the time to be clear...

So, I've got a base class and a derived class.  The base class needs to know the parameters used to create instances of the derived class (so that it can store them to disk and we can later recreate the derived instance). The base class itself doesn't need to take any parameters.

The obvious way to do this is to require the developer of the derived class to pass it's parameters into the base classes' `__init__()`.  However if possible I'd like to make it more automated; it'd be an easy mistake to get a mismatch and the whole point of the base class is to hide the machinery from those developing the derived classes.

I came up with this solution - is there anything wrong with this approach?

```
class Base(object):
  def __new__(typ, *args, **kwargs):
    obj = object.__new__(typ)
    obj._args = args
    obj._kwargs = kwargs
    return obj

class Derived(Base):
  def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
    pass # obviously will do stuff here

inst = Derived('salt', arg2='pepper')
print inst, inst._args, inst._kwargs
```

Comment: it is very common to just use init and expect any classes that inherit to call the super init...  I havent used __new__ enough to know the caveats of it...but that looks reasonable

Comment: This is an odd design.  The base class can't know what all the derived classes will need, since you never know who will subclass your class later.  Why are you doing it this way?

Comment: Cause I'm trying to save classes containing matplotlib items to disk - you can't pickle all matplotlib features.  It also allows me to restore a GUI too.

Comment: Implement `__init__` in your base class, and have your derived class invoke the base `__init__`.  No need to involve `__new__`.

Comment: Is it less of an odd design if it's a mixin, rather than the only base?